# App not getting installed on device after updating android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my android studio to 3.4.2. Until that point, everything was working perfectly fine.
But after I updated and made a few changes in the code I ran the app but unfortunately, the app does not get installed on my device anymore, it stops as soon as the build is completed.

Things I tried doing to solve the issue:
1. Restart the android studio
2. run it several times
3. kill and start the ADB

Launching app

> $ adb install-multiple -r -t F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk F:\achuth\khelo\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Device emulator-5554disconnected, monitoring stopped.
Split APKs installed in 32 s 703 ms

Comment: have you tried doing a clean and build ?

Comment: Clean build or Invalid Cache and Restart you should try it.

Comment: delete build folder(project -> app -> build), Run again

Comment: @a_local_nobody I tried cleand and build, does'nt help

Comment: @Venky tried it man, not helping

Comment: @SurajGhadge tried that too!

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio and Delete the cache in /System/Caches is useful for system